# Continuous sound while changing frequency with pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

My question is similar to the one asked in this post: [How to change continuously the frequency of a sinusoidal sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384138/how-to-change-continuously-the-frequency-of-a-sinusoidal-sound) 
But I found the solution to be a bit confusing. I want to concatenate multiple tones (that are at different frequencies) so that the tones are continuous. I'm trying to figure out the whole phase shift thing but I'm just lost. I'm currently using the code from here: http://milkandtang.com/blog/2013/02/16/making-noise-in-python/ to generate the tones.
Thank you so much! Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are working with `pyaudio`, However, if you are open to different libraries, there is an easier solution using [pydub](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydub).

Your question is two-fold.

- How to generate audio-tones?
- How to concatenate multiple tones?

[pydub](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydub) provides simple and easy high-level interface for manipulation of audio files. You can find more details / examples [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

You can install `pydub` using
`pip install pydub`

So for first part, `pydub` provides a Sine wave generator that's used below in sample example to generate sine waves of 1k,2k,3k of 3 second duration.

We then convert those to `audio_segments`. After that we concatenate them by simple appending each segment onto other.

`crossfade` is used at 2.5sec interval to prevent crackling sound at merge-point.

Here is working code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub.playback import play


#Generate 1k,2k,3k tones of 3 sec duration
tone1 = Sine(1000).to_audio_segment(duration=3000)
tone2 = Sine(2000).to_audio_segment(duration=3000)
tone3 = Sine(3000).to_audio_segment(duration=3000)

#Append each tone onto other with crossfade
multitone = tone1.append(tone2, crossfade=2500).append(tone3, crossfade=2500)


# Play final tone
play(multitone)
```

Comment: Would pydub work if I'm trying to generate sound in real time? I'm using a kinect to track hand positions, and depending on that position, I want the frequency of the sound to change. Thank you!

Comment: `pydub` works with existing audiframes. For recording you may convert pyaudio data to pydub frames. But judging from your application you can generate predetermined sets of audio-tones using `pydub` either ahead of time  or on the fly and just mix and match to kinect coordinates.