# Real time continuous sounds with Pydub

Tags: python, audio, real-time, pyaudio, pydub

I'm trying to make a program that generates sounds from a wifi probe log, so that the number of devices (within a certain distance) generate a tone, and that the rssi is to be the frequence.

I'm trying to make it as real time as possible, but can't figure out how to make the tones continuous and change the frequence based on value change.

```
'''
This program takes a log file from a
wifi probe and translates it into sound
'''

import time
import math        #import needed modules
import pyaudio     #sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
import threading
from threading import Thread
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub.playback import play
import signal


def logData():
    '''
    Takes log file data and puts it into database
    updates every 1 sec
    '''
    global dic
    global tone
    tone = []
    dic = {}
    while True:
        with open("/Users/CWT/Documents/VÆRKER/probemon.log") as f:
            for line in f:
                (key, val) = line.split()
                if val <= str(-50):
                    dic[(key)] = val
        print (dic)
        time.sleep(1)



def sound():

    '''
    Generate sounds
    '''

    # Play final tone
    while (True):
        with open("/Users/CWT/Documents/VÆRKER/probemon.log") as i:
            try:
                tone1 = Sine(abs(int(list(dic.values())[0]))).to_audio_segment(3000)            
                tone2 = Sine(abs(int(list(dic.values())[1]))).to_audio_segment(3000)        
                tone3 = Sine(abs(int(list(dic.values())[2]))).to_audio_segment(3000)
            except:
                print('Index error')
            try:
                multitone1 = tone1
                multitone2 = tone1.overlay(tone2)
                multitone3 = tone3.overlay(multitone2)
            except:
                print('Multitone error')


            try:
                if len(dic) <= 1:
                    play(multitone1.fade_in(250).fade_out(250))
                elif len(dic) == 2:
                    play(multitone2.fade_in(250).fade_out(250))
                elif len(dic) >= 3:
                    play(multitone3.fade_in(250).fade_out(250))
            except:
                print('Playback error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Thread(target = logData).start()
        time.sleep(1)
        Thread(target = sound).start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I've a solution but need a sample of probe log file.

Comment: I found a work around but it's not really realtime. Would love to see your solution. Here is an clipping of the log file:

`d8:8f:76:1a:cb:65 -43
d8:8f:76:1a:cb:65 -43
04:4f:4c:77:72:8f -51
04:4f:4c:77:72:8f -51
20:39:56:af:51:49 -39
20:39:56:af:51:49 -45
5e:e2:1d:a3:d2:da -47
5e:e2:1d:a3:d2:da -49
12:84:16:9c:75:ee -43
da:a1:19:71:4d:0c -55
48:a9:1c:c3:59:fc -55
d8:8f:76:1a:cb:65 -49`

Comment: Are you on windows platform or linux/mac?

Comment: I'm on Mac but have the wifi sniffer on a VM running Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to craft a boiler-plate solution that you can tailor per your needs.

Here's central idea

1) Read last line of log file using `os.popen` in a continuous loop that repeats every second

2) the RSSI value is very small and the difference between these values is also small. We multiply that by constant `100` here to create noticeable difference. You can try  different values.

3) Using pydub we create sine tones and play them

**Code**

```
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import os
import time

sr = 44100  # sample rate
bd = 16     # bit depth
l  = 50.0     # duration in millisec

last_line = ""  #to avoid same line played again
log_file = "probemon.log"


while True:

    line = os.popen('tail -n 1 {}'.format(log_file)).read()
    if last_line  == line:
        pass

    else:
        key, val = line.split()
        f = abs(int(val)) * 100

        #create sine wave of given freq
        sine_wave = Sine(f, sample_rate=sr, bit_depth=bd)

        #Convert waveform to audio_segment for playback and export
        sine_segment = sine_wave.to_audio_segment(duration=l)

        print "mac:{} , rssi:{}".format(key,val)
        #Play audio segment
        play(sine_segment)

        last_line = line
        time.sleep(1)  #sleep 1 sec, synch this with log file fill
```

I tested by filling up `probemon.log` file line by line from a different terminal with a delay of 1 second. The loop will wait if there is no new data.

**EDIT1**

Audio "tone" have "frequency" , when you change Frequency, tone changes. 
Based on our discussion, since we need tone to vary in real-time, we can't use `pydub` which is mostly good for offline manipulation.

`pyaudio` has a non-blocking method using callback, which allows manipulating stream data while its being played in realtime.

This solution plays audio based on last line of log continuously until log data changes.

This solution also eliminated popping / cracking sound that occurs when merging two tones.

Inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384138/how-to-change-continuously-the-frequency-of-a-sinusoidal-sound).

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from time import time,sleep
import os

CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

TT = time()
freq = 100
newfreq = 100
phase = 0
log_file = "probemon.log"

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global TT,phase,freq,newfreq
    if newfreq != freq:
        phase = 2*np.pi*TT*(freq-newfreq)+phase
        freq=newfreq
    left = (np.sin(phase+2*np.pi*freq*(TT+np.arange(frame_count)/float(RATE))))
    data = np.zeros((left.shape[0]*2,),np.float32)
    data[0::2] = left  #left data
    data[1::2] = left  #right data
    TT+=frame_count/float(RATE)
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()
tmphold = ""
try:
    while True:
        line = os.popen('tail -n 1 {}'.format(log_file)).read()
        try:
            key, val = line.split()
        except:
            key, val = "default", 0.0

        f = abs(int(val))  
        newfreq = f * 10  #update freq per log
        if newfreq != tmphold:
            tmphold = newfreq
            print "mac:{} , rssi:{} , freq:{} 
finally:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

**Result**

```
mac:default , rssi:0.0 , freq:0 Hz
mac:d8:8f:76:1a:cb:65 , rssi:-43 , freq:430 Hz
mac:04:4f:4c:77:72:8f , rssi:-51 , freq:510 Hz
mac:20:39:56:af:51:49 , rssi:-39 , freq:390 Hz
mac:20:39:56:af:51:49 , rssi:-45 , freq:450 Hz
mac:5e:e2:1d:a3:d2:da , rssi:-47 , freq:470 Hz
mac:5e:e2:1d:a3:d2:da , rssi:-49 , freq:490 Hz
mac:12:84:16:9c:75:ee , rssi:-43 , freq:430 Hz
mac:da:a1:19:71:4d:0c , rssi:-55 , freq:550 Hz
mac:d8:8f:76:1a:cb:65 , rssi:-49 , freq:490 Hz
```

Comment: Thanks it works as you said. I came up with something similar.
But what I was aiming for was _one_ tone continuously playing and changing freq depending on input. So that there would not be any breaks in the sound output.
Do you think that is doable ?

Comment: I added a solution based on `pyaudio` non blocking call back method. It plays tone continuously and changes when log RSSI changes , eliminating cracking/popping sound, and gives a continuous flow of audio.

Comment: Yeah just like that! Perfect man, thanks! But could you explain the code a little. Can't seem to grasp what the callback is doing?

Comment: callback gets called automatically and repeatedly when stream completes processing of CHUNK. Hence by controlling callback, we control the flow/data to stream. Checkout documentation https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/ , and up vote if u liked the solution.

Comment: Okay kool. I don't have enough reputation to upvote. I'll do it as soon as I get enough.